# Aggregation queries on lists of associations in 10.3

Tags: bugs, associations, query

**Bug introduced in 10.3.0 and fixed in 10.3.1**

**Bug introduced in 10.3.0 and fixed in 10.4.0**

*First bug, see first part of the question*

*Second bug, see update part*

---

Some aggregation queries applied to a list of associations (or `Dataset`'s with this structure) lock up the front end or crash the kernel in Version 10.3.

```
xx = {<|"a" -> 1|>, <|"a" -> 3|>};
Mean[xx]
(* locked up front end, with cell bracket highlighted as evaluating *)
```

The behavior is observed in *Mathematica* 10.3 on OS X El Capitan.  It is not observed in 10.2.  A bug report has been sent to Wolfram support, and I will update this post and tag it appropriately when I get a reply.

In the meantime, we are fortunate that `Total` still works, so my workaround is

```
myMean[listofassoc:{_Association..}] :=Total[listofassoc]/Length[listofassoc];
myMean[args___]:=Mean[args];
```

Note that the above code does not catch the `Dataset` case.

*Update:*
As pointed out in the comments, this bug only occurs when the associations contain single items, so

```
Mean[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 12|>}]

(* <|"a" -> 2, "b" -> 7|> *)
```

However, when the list contains a single association, a list is returned instead of a singleton

```
Mean[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>}]

(* {<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>} *)
```

which is unexpected behavior, and also different from 10.2 behavior.

Comment: Same for me with OSX 10.9.5 and MMA v10.3. `Plus@@listofassoc` also works.

Comment: Seen it on OS X 10.9.5 here, as well, and a colleague saw it on Linux and Windows 7. I'm marking it as a bug.

Comment: Confirmed in Win7 SP1 Mma 10.3 *Physical Memory Usage* goes to the roof and then the kernel crashes.

Comment: Actually the problem seem to occur only when there is one element in the association. For example `Mean[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>, <|"a" -> 3, "b" -> 12|>}]` works.

Comment: It's a bug in _Mathematica_ 10.3. We are aware of the issue.

Comment: Another workaround: `Merge[xx, Mean]`

Comment: @SquareOne Thanks, your comments have been very helpful. Your workaround using Merge is the most robust of any of the approaches I have tried.  If you post this as an Answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @DanielW Thanks. OK, I'll post an answer telling this has been confirmed as a bug, and will propose the workaround.

Comment: @ilian I see you marked this issue as fixed in 10.3.1, but I still see the wrong result for `Mean[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>}]` in that release but not in 10.2 or earlier (using Windows 7 x64).

Comment: @WReach Yes, I really meant the hang. But the list result is somewhat suspicious. I'll revert my edit to the header.

Comment: @ilian In v10.3.1 `Merge[{<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>}, Mean]` returns `<|"a" -> 1, "b" -> 2|>`  (no List)

Comment: The remaining issue has been fixed in the development version today.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As confirmed by @Stefan R, it is a bug in 10.3.

In the meanwhile, a possible workaround is :  `Merge[xx, Mean]`