# Average dataset with many repetitions?

Tags: list-manipulation, probability-or-statistics, dataset, associations

I have a dataset where each item is of the form:

```
<|"p1" -> x1, "p2" -> x2, "r1" -> y1, "r2" -> y2|>
```

The interpretation is this: `p1` and `p2` are parameters, which can take on different values (in this case represented by `x1` and `x2`), while `r1`, `r2` are the results of some simulation carried out with some specific values for the parameters `p1` and `p2`. For this particular item, the simulation was run with `p1=x1`, `p2=x2`, and the results were `r1=y1`, `r2=y2`. Now, given fixed values of the parameters `p1`, `p2`, there can be some variation in the results `r1`, `r2`. So my dataset, which is a `List` of items of the form above, has many repetitions for each particular pair of parameter values. Now what I want to do is transform this list, into another list, where the items are again of the form:

```
<|"p1" -> x1, "p2" -> x2, "r1" -> m1, "r2" -> m2|>
```

where now `m1` is the mean of `y1` for all simulations with parameter values `p1=x1`, `p2=x2`, and similarly for `m2`. So the new list has no repetitions: there is only one entry per pair of parameter values.

What's the simplest way of doing this?

My Mathematica version is 10.3.

Comment: Have you looked at GroupBy? http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html

Comment: Related, possibly even duplicate: [(4332)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4332/121), [(60913)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/60913/121)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Stealing Pickett's example:

```
Values @ GroupBy[res, Query[{"p1", "p2"}], Merge@Mean]
```

> ```
> {
>  <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 1, "r1" -> 64/5, "r2" -> 20|>, 
>  <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 2, "r1" -> 64/5, "r2" -> 156/5|>
> }
> ```

And if `m` keys are required:

```
<|KeyDrop[#, {"r1", "r2"}], "m1" -> #r1, "m2" -> #r2|> & /@ %
```

Comment: that is a bit overcomplicated. `Values@GroupBy[res, #[[{"p1", "p2"}]] &, Mean]` is all you need.

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch this crashes my kernel :/

Comment: really! what are you running? I am on OS X 10.10.5 and Mma V10.3.1 and it works fine

Comment: +1 Very nice and readable. And if I wanted the standard deviations of the results as well, I could use `Values @ GroupBy[res, Query[{"p1", "p2"}], Merge@StandardDeviation]`. Great!

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch Your comment also crashes my kernel. I have v10.3.0 on Linux.

Comment: @becko interesting. no problems on mac and is faster

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch `Mean` alone triggers [this bug](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/98277/142).  WRI claims it was broken in 10.3.0 and fixed in 10.3.1, but on Windows I still see the wrong result in 10.3.1 when `Mean` is applied to a list containing a single association (no crash though).  `Merge@Mean` is the workaround.

Comment: @WReach it is strange that the bug persists on Windows (and Linux) but not on Mac. Hopefully someone from WRI will read and can comment

Comment: @MikeHoneychurch ilian of WRI has acknowledged the singleton list issue on [another comment thread](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98277/aggregation-queries-on-lists-of-associations-in-10-3?noredirect=1#comment282582_98277).

Comment: This is an excellent answer. We may consider two variations: instead of Query[{"p1","p2"}] we may use Lookup[{"p1","p2"}], as done by Edmund or Part[{#p1,#p2}]&, as done by Mike Honeychurch. I constructed a list data consisting of 100000 associations and did a timing of GroupBy[data, ... ]]; for each of the three alternatives. I found that Lookup is a little bit faster than Part, while Query is almost 100 times slower than Lookup. So for large lists, I would prefer Lookup.

Answer (score 4):

One way:

```
gathered = GatherBy[res, {#p1, #p2} &]

<| "p1" -> First[#]["p1"],
   "p2" -> First[#]["p2"],
   Merge[#[[All, {Key["r1"], Key["r2"]}]], Mean]
   |> & /@ gathered
```

Test:

```
res = {
   <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 1, "r1" -> 10, "r2" -> 20|>,
   <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 1, "r1" -> 15, "r2" -> 20|>,
   <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 1, "r1" -> 12, "r2" -> 20|>,
   <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 1, "r1" -> 13, "r2" -> 20|>,
   <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 1, "r1" -> 14, "r2" -> 20|>,
   <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 2, "r1" -> 10, "r2" -> 20|>,
   <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 2, "r1" -> 15, "r2" -> 30|>,
   <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 2, "r1" -> 12, "r2" -> 34|>,
   <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 2, "r1" -> 13, "r2" -> 32|>,
   <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 2, "r1" -> 14, "r2" -> 40|>
   };

gathered = GatherBy[res, {#p1, #p2} &]
<| "p1" -> First[#]["p1"],
   "p2" -> First[#]["p2"],
   Merge[#[[All, {Key["r1"], Key["r2"]}]], Mean]
   |> & /@ gathered

(* Out: {<|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 1, "r1" -> 64/5, "r2" -> 20|>, <|"p1" -> 1, 
  "p2" -> 2, "r1" -> 64/5, "r2" -> 156/5|>} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Update** borrowing from Kuba.

```
Join @@@ Normal@GroupBy[dat, Query[{"p1", "p2"}],
   KeyMap[StringReplace[#, "r" -> "m"] &]@*Mean@*Query[All, {"r1", "r2"}]]
```

---

**Original post**

Generate some data:

```
SeedRandom[123];
dat = Join[#, <|"r1" -> RandomReal[10], "r2" -> RandomReal[20]|>] & /@ 
   Flatten@ConstantArray[Table[<|"p1" -> i, "p2" -> j|>, {i, 2}, {j, 2}], 4];
```

Use `GroupBy` and a few `Association` related functions.

```
KeyValueMap[
  Join[
    AssociationThread[{"p1", "p2"} -> #1],
    AssociationThread[{"m1", "m2"} -> Mean@Query[All, {"r1", "r2"} /* Values]@#2]
    ] &
  ]@GroupBy[Lookup[{"p1", "p2"}]]@dat

(*
{<|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 1, "m1" -> 3.19274, "m2" -> 14.7372|>, 
 <|"p1" -> 1, "p2" -> 2, "m1" -> 4.41867, "m2" -> 11.8091|>, 
 <|"p1" -> 2, "p2" -> 1, "m1" -> 3.23234, "m2" -> 7.25984|>, 
 <|"p1" -> 2, "p2" -> 2, "m1" -> 6.18188, "m2" -> 6.79438|>}
*)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

not an answer. i just wanted to paste output to show the bug has been fixed on Mac

[image]

Comment: @ilian why does the bug persist on Windows but not on Mac?